# Rails join and filter by primary model ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Why are these two queries producing different result?

```
FbGroup.where('fb_groups.id IN (?)', ids).length
> 300

FbGroup.joins(:fb_posts).where('fb_groups.id IN (?)', ids).length
> 500
```

My desired result is to join `fb_posts` but before I join I'd like to filter `fb_groups` by specific ids. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Why are these two queries producing different result?

The join might result in 1:N (one to many) records. Eg. if one `FbGroup` has two `FbPost`, you will get two records when you join.

> My desired result is to join fb_posts but before I join I'd like to filter fb_groups by specific ids. How can I do that?

Your second query already does this. When you filter with the join or join and then filter in an outer query, you would still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

> My desired result is to join `fb_posts` but before I join I'd like to filter `fb_groups` by specific ids. How can I do that?

I used `fb_groups` with `id` `1`, `2` and `3` just for example

```
FbGroup.where(id: [1, 2, 3]).joins(:fb_posts).count
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's duplicating records in joins. You should use group_by with joins to eliminate it. Try,

```
FbGroup.joins(:fb_posts).where('fb_groups.id IN (?)', ids).group('fb_groups.id').length
```

Please correct if I am wrong.